# Finding the future value and interest rate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The problem I am having is with the last for loop that calculates the future value near the bottom. What I'm looking for is the modify it so that it displays the interest rate and value for each year. It should be displayed next to the year in this format: year=1 interest=750 value= 10750.

```js
var again = "y";
var interest = []
var year = []
var value = []
do {
  var futureValue
  var value = 0
  //get user entries
  do {
    var investment = prompt("Enter investment amount as xxxxx.xx", 10000);
    investment = parseInt(investment);
    if (isNaN(investment)) {
      alert("Investment must be a number");
    }
  }
  while (isNaN(investment));

  do {
    var rate = prompt("Enter interest rate as xx.x", 7.5);
    rate = parseFloat(rate);
    if (1 > rate || 15 < rate) {
      alert("Rate must be below 15 and above 0");
    }
  }
  while (1 > rate || 15 < rate);
  var years = prompt("Enter number of years", 10);
  years = parseInt(years);

  //calculate future value
  futureValue = investment;
  for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * rate / 100);
    interest += (futureValue * rate / 100) + "\n";
    year += i;
    value = futureValue;

  }
  futureValue = parseInt(futureValue);
  again = prompt("Repeat Entries?", "y");
}
while (again == "y");
```

Answer (score 0):

So aggregate the years (using array) into a string that contains the info you want. See the `msgs` variable.

```js
var again = "y";
var interest = []
var year = []
var value = []
do {
  var futureValue
  var value = 0
  //get user entries
  do {
    var investment = prompt("Enter investment amount as xxxxx.xx", 10000);
    investment = parseInt(investment);
    if (isNaN(investment)) {
      alert("Investment must be a number");
    }
  }
  while (isNaN(investment));

  do {
    var rate = prompt("Enter interest rate as xx.x", 7.5);
    rate = parseFloat(rate);
    if (1 > rate || 15 < rate) {
      alert("Rate must be below 15 and above 0");
    }
  }
  while (1 > rate || 15 < rate);
  var years = prompt("Enter number of years", 10);
  years = parseInt(years);

  //calculate future value
  futureValue = investment;
  var msgs = []
  for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * rate / 100);
    interest += (futureValue * rate / 100) + "\n";
    year += i;
    value = futureValue;
    msgs.push("year: " + i + ", interest: " + (+interest).toFixed(2) + ", value: " + (+value).toFixed(2))
  }
  futureValue = parseInt(futureValue);
  again = prompt(msgs.join("\n") + "\nRepeat Entries?", "y");
}
while (again == "y");
```